# Являются ли однокоренными слова "станция" и "остановка"?

Tags: однокоренные-слова, морфология

Являются ли однокоренными слова *станция* и *остановка*?
[Викисловарь](http://ru.wiktionary.org/) приводит следующий морфологический разбор этих слов:
[*станция*](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/станция) - корень: -станциj-; окончание: -я.
[*остановка*](http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/остановка) - приставка: о-; корень: -станов-; суффикс: -к-; окончание: -а.
Хочется услышать ваше мнение. Может быть [Викисловарь](http://ru.wiktionary.org/) ошибается?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> **Станция.** Происходит от польск. stancja
> (XVII в.) или stacja, из лат. statio
> «стояние; местопребывание», далее из
> stāre «стоять», далее из праиндоевр.
> *sta- «стоять» Русск. станция — начиная с Петра I.
>
> **Стоять, от которого постепенно образовалась "остановка".** Происходит
> от праслав. формы *stojati, от которой
> в числе прочего произошли: ст.-слав.
> стояти, стоѬ (греч. ἵστασθαι); ср.:
> укр. стояти, стою́, болг. стоя́,
> сербохорв. сто̀jи̑м, ста̀jати,
> словенск. stojím, státi «стоять»,
> чешск. stojím, stát, словацк. stojím,
> stáť, польск. stoję, stać, в.-луж.
> stejeć (из stojać), н.-луж. stojaś,
> stojm. Праслав.* stojati, *stojǫ,
> связанное чередованием гласных со
> stati (стать), соответствует оск.
> staít «stat», stahínt, staie(n)t
> «stant», умбр. stahu «sto» (*stai̯ō),
> др.-инд. sthitás «стоящий», греч.
> στατός — то же, лат. status. От stō
> (*stāi̯ō), stārе «стоять», далее —
> лит. stóti, stóju «становиться,
> вступать», др.-прусск. роstāt
> «становиться», др.-инд. tíṣṭhati
> «остается на месте, стоит», авест.
> hištaiti «стоит», греч. ἵστημι
> «ставлю», лат. sistō — то же,
> др.-в.-нем. sta^n, ste^n «стоять»,
> ирл. táu «есмь» (*stāi̯ō).
>
> Использованы данные словаря М.
> Фасмера.

Эти слова нельзя считать однокоренными в русском языке, но они определенно родственны по происхождению.

Answer (score 2):

[[@a1ip](/users/1318/a1ip)](/users/1318/a1ip), здесь дело в том, что надо различать синхронический и дахронический (я бы их назвал даже диахронистским и синхронистским) подходы к морфологии слова. По-простому - определиться, говорим ли мы о сложившейся традиции и практических нуждах, либо исследуем историю слова.

С точки зрения исторического подхода, корень в обоих словах - "стан/ста" (Н там может быть корневым или протетическим, это отдельный разговор). Но для современных носителей языка вычленение такого морфа, во-первых, затруднено, во-вторых, не представляет практической надобности.

Поэтому викисловарь вслед за другими словарями (например, типичным "школьным" словарём Тихонова) совершенно законно не выделяет из общей основы исторического корня. 
Ошибки там нет.

Вот в отношении выделения приставки О в слове "остановка" при корне "станов" - не уверен. Выглядит не очень логичным. Корень в таком случае должен быть "останов" (как у Тихонова). Либо уж тогда выделять всю историческую структуру: о/стан/ов/к/а.

Comment: Вполне логично. Становиться -> остановиться (приставочный) -> остановка (суффиксальный способ). К тому же есть слово "перестановка". **Остановка** - означает окончание процесса, а **перестановка** - сам процесс изменения **расстановки** вещей.

Answer (score 1):

Тут ведь закавыка в том, что нужно учитывать происхождение слова. И получается, что слово `станция`  является родоначальником для своего "гнезда" слов, в который входят `станционный` и пр. А `остановка` - это остановка, т.е. где останавливаются или остаются. Я бы ставил вопрос по-другому: все-таки в остановке корень **-станов-**, или **-стан-**, или еще что.

Да и про суффикс -ц- в русском языке я не слышал.

Comment: @gecube, если я правильно Вас понял, в слове *станция* корень точно не **-стан-**, а следовательно слово *остановка* при любых раскладах с ним не однокоренное?

Comment: Станция - заимствование из польского (stancja или stacja) или латинского (statio). И не образовано от русскоязычной основы -стан- (ну, нет суффикса -ц-)

И меня очень смущает возможость параллелей и чередований. Стать - становиться, остановить - останавливаться.

Answer (score 1):

Изначальный корень, конечно, **-ст-**, наверное индоевропейского происхождения. А наворочено от этого корня в русском, по крайней мере, языке - и перечислять не буду.

Comment: Высказывается такое вот, созвучное Вашему, мнение: "Тут смотря как смотреть. Этимологически эти два слова точно произошли от одного корня. Но в современном русском их уже не считают однокоренными. То есть в исторической, или как говорят, диахронической перспективе они родственные слова. А в синхронической перспективе - они не однокоренные уже."